# XSLT for each line items per group order

Tags: xslt, orders

I am new to XSLT Mapping space and I would like to ask some expert advice on my transformation. I have a flat XML file that I would like to have it structured per shipment number with its corresponding Line Items and Line Item Number. any help would be greatly appreciated.

this is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>
<Line_Items>
    <Delivery_Date>2014-03-25T06:00:00.000+1000</Delivery_Date>
    <SAP_Order>518748492</SAP_Order>
    <SAP_Delivery>416065495</SAP_Delivery>
    <SAP_Shipment>2653107 - 6:00 AM - R/L</SAP_Shipment>
    <External_ID>BRBC69J250314</External_ID>
    <Time_Slot>1899/12/31</Time_Slot>
    <Customer_Order>R-41542740A</Customer_Order>
    <Outlet_Number>4202629</Outlet_Number>
    <Material>951586</Material>
    <Material_Description>1.25 PET X12 MT FRK LSPK</Material_Description>
    <Order_Qty>48</Order_Qty>
    <Pallets>22</Pallets>
    <Gross_Weight>19329.08</Gross_Weight>
    <Dispatcher_Message>AWH</Dispatcher_Message>
    <Driver_Message>R/L - 1R4228V</Driver_Message>
    <Pallet_Count>22</Pallet_Count>
    <Shipping_Point>1043</Shipping_Point>
</Line_Items>
<Line_Items>
    <Delivery_Date>2014-03-25T06:00:00.000+1000</Delivery_Date>
    <SAP_Order>518748492</SAP_Order>
    <SAP_Delivery>416065495</SAP_Delivery>
    <SAP_Shipment>2653107 - 6:00 AM - R/L</SAP_Shipment>
    <External_ID>BRBC69J250314</External_ID>
    <Time_Slot>1899/12/31</Time_Slot>
    <Customer_Order>R-41542740A</Customer_Order>
    <Outlet_Number>4202629</Outlet_Number>
    <Material>950064</Material>
    <Material_Description>1.25 PET X12 DIET COKE</Material_Description>
    <Order_Qty>192</Order_Qty>
    <Pallets>22</Pallets>
    <Gross_Weight>19329.08</Gross_Weight>
    <Dispatcher_Message>AWH</Dispatcher_Message>
    <Driver_Message>R/L - 1R4228V</Driver_Message>
    <Pallet_Count>22</Pallet_Count>
    <Shipping_Point>1043</Shipping_Point>
</Line_Items>
<Line_Items>
    <Delivery_Date>2014-03-25T09:00:00.000+1000</Delivery_Date>
    <SAP_Order>518748492</SAP_Order>
    <SAP_Delivery>416065496</SAP_Delivery>
    <SAP_Shipment>2653108 - 9:00 AM - R/L</SAP_Shipment>
    <External_ID>BRBC70J250314</External_ID>
    <Time_Slot>1899/12/31</Time_Slot>
    <Customer_Order>R-41542740A</Customer_Order>
    <Outlet_Number>4202629</Outlet_Number>
    <Material>950055</Material>
    <Material_Description>2.0 PET X8 COCA-COLA</Material_Description>
    <Order_Qty>1056</Order_Qty>
    <Pallets>22</Pallets>
    <Gross_Weight>19294.88</Gross_Weight>
    <Dispatcher_Message>AWH</Dispatcher_Message>
    <Driver_Message>R/L - 1R4228C</Driver_Message>
    <Pallet_Count>22</Pallet_Count>
    <Shipping_Point>1043</Shipping_Point>
</Line_Items>
</Orders>
```

I would like this to be the target XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>       
<WhsDockets>    
    <WhsDocket>
        <Identifier>
            <Reference>2653107 - 6:00 AM - R/L</Reference>
            <DocketType>ORD</DocketType>
        </Identifier>
        <DocketDetail>
            <WarehouseCode>ROC</WarehouseCode>
        </DocketDetail>
        <DocketLines>
            <DocketLine>
                <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                <Product>951586</Product>
                <Description>1.25 PET X12 MT FRK LSPK</Description>
                <QuantityFromClientOrder>48</QuantityFromClientOrder>
                <ProductUQ>CAS</ProductUQ>
            </DocketLine>
            <DocketLine>
                <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
                <Product>950064</Product>
                <Description>1.25 PET X12 DIET COKE</Description>
                <QuantityFromClientOrder>192</QuantityFromClientOrder>
                <ProductUQ>CAS</ProductUQ>
            </DocketLine>
        </DocketLines>
    </WhsDocket>
    <WhsDocket>
        <Identifier>
            <Reference>2653108 - 9:00 AM - R/L</Reference>
            <DocketType>ORD</DocketType>
        </Identifier>
        <DocketDetail>
            <WarehouseCode>ROC</WarehouseCode>
        </DocketDetail>
        <DocketLines>
            <DocketLine>
                <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                <Product>950055</Product>
                <Description>2.0 PET X8 COCA-COLA</Description>
                <QuantityFromClientOrder>1056</QuantityFromClientOrder>
                <ProductUQ>CAS</ProductUQ>
            </DocketLine>
        </DocketLines>
    </WhsDocket>
</WhsDockets>
```

but I would need to have the corresponding Line items under the same reference Number and add a line item number to distinguish it but this is what im getting.

```
<WhsDocket>
            <Identifier>
                <Reference>2653107 - 6:00 AM - R/L</Reference>
                <DocketType>ORD</DocketType>
            </Identifier>
            <DocketDetail>
                <WarehouseCode>ROC</WarehouseCode>
            </DocketDetail>
            <DocketLines>
                <DocketLine>
                    <Product>951586</Product>
                    <Description>1.25 PET X12 MT FRK LSPK</Description>
                    <QuantityFromClientOrder>48</QuantityFromClientOrder>
                    <ProductUQ>CAS</ProductUQ>
                </DocketLine>
            </DocketLines>
        </WhsDocket>
        <WhsDocket>
            <Identifier>
                <Reference>2653107 - 6:00 AM - R/L</Reference>
                <DocketType>ORD</DocketType>
            </Identifier>
            <DocketDetail>
                <WarehouseCode>ROC</WarehouseCode>
            </DocketDetail>
            <DocketLines>
                <DocketLine>
                    <Product>950064</Product>
                    <Description>1.25 PET X12 DIET COKE</Description>
                    <QuantityFromClientOrder>192</QuantityFromClientOrder>
                    <ProductUQ>CAS</ProductUQ>
                </DocketLine>
            </DocketLines>
        </WhsDocket>
        <WhsDocket>
            <Identifier>
                <Reference>2653108 - 9:00 AM - R/L</Reference>
                <DocketType>ORD</DocketType>
            </Identifier>
            <DocketDetail>
                <WarehouseCode>ROC</WarehouseCode>
            </DocketDetail>
            <DocketLines>
                <DocketLine>
                    <Product>950055</Product>
                    <Description>2.0 PET X8 COCA-COLA</Description>
                    <QuantityFromClientOrder>1056</QuantityFromClientOrder>
                    <ProductUQ>CAS</ProductUQ>
                </DocketLine>
            </DocketLines>
        </WhsDocket>
    </WhsDockets>
```

this is the XSLT I have created.

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <XmlInterchange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService/">
        <Payload>
            <WhsDockets>
                <xsl:for-each select="Orders/Line_Items">
                    <WhsDocket>
                        <Identifier>
                            <Reference>
                                <xsl:value-of select="SAP_Shipment"/>
                            </Reference>
                            <DocketType>ORD</DocketType>
                        </Identifier>
                        <DocketDetail>
                            <WarehouseCode>ROC</WarehouseCode>
                        </DocketDetail>
                        <DocketLines>
                            <DocketLine>
                                <Product>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Material"/>
                                </Product>
                                <Description>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Material_Description"/>
                                </Description>
                                <QuantityFromClientOrder>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Order_Qty"/>
                                </QuantityFromClientOrder>
                                <ProductUQ>CAS</ProductUQ>
                            </DocketLine>
                        </DocketLines>
                    </WhsDocket>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </WhsDockets>
        </Payload>
    </XmlInterchange>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. Would you like us to give comments on your XSLT, or would you like us to fix something that is broken? If so, can you show the output that you _actually want_ next to the output that you are currently getting (and showing)?

Comment: Thanks Abel for your comments.I have edited my target sample XML. As Im a beginner on this things. I would like to know how to group this items under one Reference Tag and also how to get the corresponding Line Item number. Thanks again and have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "grouping" problem, and in XSLT 1.0 the technique that is usually used is called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

First you define a key to represent the group. In your case you are grouping `Line_Items` elements by `SAP_Shipment` element, so you would define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="items" match="Line_Items" use="SAP_Shipment" />
```

You then select the `Line_Items` element that occurs first in the keyfor its given value of `SAP_Shipment`. This represents the start of each group

```
<xsl:for-each select="Line_Items[generate-id() = generate-id(key('items',SAP_Shipment)[1])]">
```

You can then get all the items in the group (including the first one), using the key:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('items',SAP_Shipment)" />
```

Try this XSLT for starters

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="items" match="Line_Items" use="SAP_Shipment" />

    <xsl:template match="Orders">
        <WhsDockets>
            <xsl:for-each select="Line_Items[generate-id() = generate-id(key('items',SAP_Shipment)[1])]">
                <WhsDocket>
                    <Identifier><xsl:value-of select="SAP_Shipment" /></Identifier>
                    <DocketLines>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('items',SAP_Shipment)" />
                    </DocketLines>
                </WhsDocket>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </WhsDockets>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Line_Items">
        <DocketLine>
            <LineNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></LineNumber>
            <Product><xsl:value-of select="Material" /></Product>        
        </DocketLine>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: If you are able to use XSLT 2.0, then you could make use of the xsl:for-each-group construct. See http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1314.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim for the detailed helpful input. This will greatly jumpstart my XSLT journey. I will need to get full understanding on how the generate-id() fully works. Again thanks for the tips. cheers!